# The use of centrifugal force in highschool physics classes

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

I am a retired theoretical physicist in the Netherlands. I am currently trying to promote the exact sciences by helping highschool students with their mathematics, physics and chemistry studies.

I am impressed with the general level and sophistication of the modern physics books used by these highschool students. The courses were written by teams of around 15 teachers or physicists. And in general they are excellent. However I found out one peculiarity: the books completely avoid the term "centrifugal force". At some point they do introduce the force $F = mv^2/r$ for circular motion of a particle or object. However, they then use the name "centripetal force" for it. Strange, because as we all know the force $F$ is pointing outward instead of inward. I can only speculate that some members on the team of authors were against the concept of "centrifugal force" because they considered it a pseudo-force rather than a true force. But that is the position of purists; in practice centrifugal force is a useful concept.

Yesterday a student, preparing for his final exam, showed me an exercise about a double star. Questions were asked about the period and speed of their motions, the radius of their orbit, even about the Doppler shift as measured by astronomers. Then there was this question: explain why the two stars are attracted to each other by the gravitational force, but that this does not lead to them moving towards each other. I laughed, because -in my humble opinion- the simplest explanation is that the gravitational forces are balanced by the centrifugal forces. Hence the orbits are stable. Yet I knew that the official answer could not involve the centrifugal force; and other valid answers in terms of the potential energy and kinetic energy and/or conservation of angular momentum would be too complicated. Indeed, the official answer was vague and evasive: The two stars will not approach each other despite their gravitational pull, because they are moving in a stable orbit around a centre. Sure, but that is what the students were asked to explain!

A long story. My point is that is peculiar to avoid the term "centrifugal force" and instead attach the name "centripetal force" to $F$. What is your opinion on this matter?

Comment: The centrifugal force IS a pseudo-force.

Answer (score 1):

I have myself just moved from a place that had outlawed centrifugal, to a place whereby schoolchildren are routinely taught by the centrifugal effect and the new students are basically universally confused, as opposed to half the students being confused without it. One of the easy ways they get confused is that they would draw both centripetal and centrifugal ``forces'', and then "derive" that curving away from straight line motion is impossible.

The fact of the matter is that these concepts are incredibly poorly taught in general. What is really needed is a coherence in the overall scheme, so that students can learn a deterministic method that they can trust to always work. The simplest choice is to stick religiously to an inertial frame of reference and only use Newtonian framework. As such, centrifugal will not appear.

In particular, my favoured way to disabuse students of the centrifugal idea, which, to date has an 100% success rate, even with business school students, is to simply help them derive the centrifugal and coriolis effect terms directly. One look at the ugliness, and they would learn to permanently disassociate themselves with the concept. Every step of the way we have to go slow and make sure the students themselves agree with the steps. Of course, I would always remember to remind them that there is still an Euler term that is not yet derived, for their own sanity.

To help students not get confused, it is important to use the physical terms in a rather pedantic manner. The word "force" should only be used when one can identify a physical interaction that gives rise to it. As such, centripetal is an acceleration, never a force. A string's tension, or gravitational pull, is the real physical force, the real physical interaction, that supplies the centripetal acceleration needed to cause circular motion. The usual statement of N2L, namely $\sum \vec F = m \vec a$ is really a statement of cause = effect, and so it should be emphasised to students that there is a natural separation, and one should not just randomly move terms across the equal sign in that equation. Again, this is yet another reason to disfavour centrifugal concept, unless one is ready to consider non-inertial, rotating frames of reference. That is, not only the student must be physically savvy enough to handle the confusing concept of a rotating frame, but the teacher who is attempting to teach that, is also somewhat obligated to do a good enough job of teaching it.

The concept of centripetal acceleration is routinely taught, and people tend to think that there is no problems with the standard treatment. However, students can be rather confused, even if they can memorise and apply them properly. A few more words can easily help students iron out kinks in their understanding. For example, if we wish to analyse satellite orbits, we may talk about
$$ F_\text{grav} = m \frac{v^2}r = m a_\text{centripetal}
$$
It would be helpful to make it exceedingly clear that some real interaction force is necessary. Students should not be allowed to answer with "centripetal force" anywhere in their argumentation. It is good for students to derive in a variety of ways the centripetal acceleration term, multiplied by mass or not, and then reason out what that means. If it is due to string tension, then it is clear that the string tension is not necessarily proportional to mass, and thus the same tension would cause objects of different mass and speeds to rotate with different radii. The relationship between these three quantities needs to be explicitly stated. Since it is typical that we are considering objects with fixed masses, that means that it is particularly helpful to assert that, for any object moving at any velocity, the application of any arbitrary force perpendicular to its motion, would cause a rotation of its velocity according to a radius that is determined from the centripetal acceleration formula.

And then students will be able to confidently answer that binary stars will not be colliding radially because of a combination of N1L and this---The usual confusion as to why students might think that pulling between things causes them to always move towards each other is because they still think erroneously that $ F = m v$ and thus are in pre-Newtonian conception of motion, and hence why N1L is part of the answer (to state, as Newton did, that the ancients were wrong and we now know better), and then that the true reason is that the binary stars have enough velocities perpendicular to their mutual gravitational attractive forces such that the gravitational forces manage to supply roughly the centripetal acceleration and not enough radial acceleration to lead to a collision. Such an answer is the one that demonstrate an actual understanding of the situation, as opposed to a quick and dirty pseudo-explanation that they might vaguely parrot and not understand.

Of course, I agree with you that renaming centrifugal effect term as centripetal is a sin even greater than that, and definitely should be punished by jail time.

Answer (score 0):

$F=\frac{mv^2}{R}$ is the centripetal force and it does act toward the center of circular motion. It is the force that describes the circular motion in an inertial (non accelerating) frame of an observer, such as a person on the road observing a car in circular motion. The force, in this case, is static friction between the wheels and the road acting toward the center of circular motion preventing the car from moving off in a straight line.

In the non-inertial (accelerating) frame of the object undergoing circular motion, such as a person in the car moving in a circle, it is called the centrifugal force. It is force used to explain the apparent force that acts  outward from the center of circular motion on the person. It is a pseudo force because what the person is actually experiencing is the effect of the his/her inertia, as opposed to an actual physical force.

With regard to celestial objects orbiting one another, the force of gravity acts as the centripetal force. The force on each body acts towards the center of mass (barycenter) of the orbiting bodies. Without gravity, each body would fly off in a straight line, per Newton's 1st law.

Hope this helps.

Comment: F = kinetic energy? lol

Comment: The OP clearly understands the topic and doesnt need an explanation. And you have definitely muddied things up because you did not point out that there is a sign change between centripetal and centrifugal effects. You merely stated the magnitude of the term. Students would be utterly confused as to why something can be pointing at both directions at once. And how would you justify the use of Newtonian mechanics in the non-inertial frame?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent  I don't think I "muddied things up", thanks. By saying one force acts in and the other out is the same thing as saying the sign is opposite.  Anyway you have your answer and I have mine and I see no need to justify mine to you.

Comment: I'm increasingly of the opinion that we should just stop using the synonym and say "net force pointed towards the center" to avoid the idea that there's a special kind of force called "centripetal"

Comment: @gs What synonym? To avoid the idea that there is what?

Comment: @gs Centripetal force is simply an umbrella term meaning a force tending towards the center of circular motion. It is not meant to describe what the specific nature of that force is. It could be gravity. It could be tension in a string. It could be static friction. I see nothing wrong with the term as long as the nature of the specific force is identified. Anyway, it's really a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Centrifugal forces are odd in that they have no physical cause - they are bookkeeping inventions created solely for the purpose of explaining things in non-inertial frames which would otherwise have no explanation at all. In your example of the binary stars, what is the physical cause of the outward pushing centrifugal force? It's not gravity, or electromagnetism, or any other real force with a real physical cause. The centrifugal force can take any arbitrary magnitude you want, dependent solely on your choice of reference frame. You mention that in the star example, "the gravitational forces are balanced by the centrifugal forces", but that's only true in one particular non-inertial frame, in all other frames it is false. In inertial frames, the centrifugal force doesn't even exist.

Centripetal forces are real and invariant between inertial frames. Centrifugal forces are fictitious, have no physical cause, and vary between reference frames. I agree centrifugal force can be a useful concept in some scenarios, but it's usually simpler to deal with real physical causes in inertial frames.

Comment: "I agree centrifugal force can be a useful concept in some scenarios..."  It certainly can. Consider the centrifuge. The "pseudo" centrifugal force is responsible for separating fluids of different densities or separating liquids from solids.

Comment: @BobD That simply cannot be, by definition. No real world physics can be dependent upon a fictitious anything. It can only be a convenient shorthand. The real explanation of what a centrifuge is actually doing, is that, usually, stuff in a liquid suspension are so light that thermal excitation is sufficient to keep them up, even if their densities are bigger than the liquid, and should have thus sunk to the bottom. The rotation makes it such that the thermal excitation, which depends upon temperature but not rotation, is no longer capable of supplying centripetal acceleration, thus separation.

Comment: @BobD Centrifugal forces aren't real. This is equivalent to saying that what makes an elevator go up and down is the building moving around it, or what makes a car move forward is a planetary-scale force accelerating the entire earth behind it. Conveniently true in a particular reference frame, but unrelated to physical causes.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I know they aren't real. I said as much in my answer. But the phenomena they address, inertia, is real. And that's why I mentioned the centrifuge as an application related to the phenomena See also:

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifuge#:~:text=A%20centrifuge%20is%20a%20device,various%20components%20of%20a%20fluid.

https://druckerdiagnostics.com/knowledge/how-a-centrifuge-works/

https://www.excedr.com/blog/what-is-a-centrifuge/

https://www.biocompare.com/Lab-Equipment/Laboratory-Centrifuges/

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/centrifuge

https://www.jove.com/v/5019/an-introduction-to-the-centrifuge

https://ehs.stanford.edu/reference/centrifuge-safety

Comment: @NuclearHoagie As you can see from the links, it is common to use the term centrifugal force in connection with centrifuges, though the actual phenomenon is inertia.